# How to convert curtin storage configuration to cloud-init disk_setup

Tags: server, cloud, cloud-init, curtin

I am using the Cloud Images for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 LTS to provision a template image for further provisioning.

I previously tried using the Live Server Images with `autoinstall` and had no sucess with the configuration by adding my `user-data` configuration under the `user-data` of the `autoinstall` file.

I do have a `curtin` based storage configuration that I wish to write in my `user-data` file using `cloud-init`. The configuration is as follows:

```yaml
storage:
    config:
      - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/vda, wipe: superblock-recursive,
         preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false, type: disk,
         id: disk-sda}
      - {device: disk-sda, size: 512M, wipe: superblock, flag: boot,
         number: 1, preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition,
         id: partition-0}
      - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-0, preserve: false, type: format,
         id: format-0, label: boot}
      - {device: disk-sda, size: 30%, wipe: superblock, flag: '',
         number: 2, preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
      - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-2, preserve: false, type: format,
         id: format-1, label: root}
      - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-1}
      - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '',
         number: 3, preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-3}
      - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-3, preserve: false, type: format,
         id: format-2, label: root}
      - {device: format-2, path: /home, type: mount, id: mount-2}
      - {device: format-0, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-0}
```

I am not sure how to map the `autoinstall` / `curtin` schema to that of `disk_setup` and `fs_setup` of `cloud-init`.

Is there some tool that can help me convert one schema to the other?